# Send PHP Array to Javascript and then select random images from array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here's my PHP code:

```
    <?php
        $all_images = glob("Images/Classes/{*.png, *.PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
        echo json_encode($all_images);
        shuffle($all_images);
    ?>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
function Images(){
var i;
var z = Math.floor($('.Images').height() / 105); //Var z is the amount of images which fit in my div called .Images        
var images = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($all_images); ?>' ); //Get Array from PHP which contains all images in the folder.
for (i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var noextension = images[i].substring(0, images[i].lastIndexOf("."));
    var name = noextension.substring(noextension.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var final = "/Wiki/" + name + ".php";
    a.setAttribute("href", final);
    var x = document.createElement('img');
    x.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
    x.setAttribute("alt", name);
    x.setAttribute("title", name);
    a.appendChild(x);
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images')[0].appendChild(a);
    }
};
```

I've finally made this program so it actually works, thanks to you guys, but I still have a problem. The problem is that the PHP Code pastes a line into the HTML code. But the PHP code shouldn't write anything. If as example I move the PHP code from the div Images to a different DIV, the array will pop up in that other div. So why is the PHP code writing something in the HTML code? And how can I prevent this? [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkVfO.png)

**EDIT:** I fixed it by adding document.getElementsByClassName('Images')[0].innerHTML = ""; in javascript.

Comment: try `x.setAttribute("src", images[i]);`. `Images` should be an array of either objects or strings (as returned from the server, I'm not sure what `glob` produces without looking it up). If you're not sure what the structure is, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(images));` and it'll show you what the structure of the data is. Either way it'll be an array I'm sure, and you'll need to access each index in turn. At the moment you're trying to put the whole array as an attribute of your HTML tag.

Comment: Try removing `json_encode()` in your JS, since you are getting from PHP a json response.

Comment: So I've changed my code a bit, more parts of it work now, as example the a href first only added .php to the string, not it removes the extension and then add .php. Also, receiving the array from PHP seems to be going just fine, but displaying the images is where it all goes wrong, without me able to explain why. I updated my Javascript code and also added the error I'm getting, hopefully it helps you guys understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You missed getting one element from a collection here:
```document.getElementsByClassName('Images')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').appendChild(x);```
After ```document.getElementsByClassName('Images')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')``` you will have an array of elements. You need to add ```[0]``` to call ```appendChild(x)``` function on a first link.

Comment: Instead of trying to do it in a single line, I used two lines using the code Vyacheslav suggested. It still has one bug though, so I updated it above. Maybe you know how to fix this last, minor bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include img inside anchor tag before. like this:

```
a.appendChild(x);
```

And then yours:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Images')[0].appendChild(a);
```

If I've understood you right, and error description too, it can't find the needed element with your desired structure

Comment: It actually works now, but it still has one error, I editted everything again, so maybe you know how to fix this last, minor problem?

Comment: try to remove echo json_encode($all_images); from php - you have at first echo in php code, then another one into JS function. I hope that's it and your app now working :) And also my answer was useful for you

Comment: I couldn't delete that line of code from the PHP, since it's needed to send the array to Javascript. But what I could and actually did do was change the javascript, to clear the div called Images before typing something. And I accepted your answer and marked it as usefull, I hope :P

Comment: you're using echo in 2 places  -one of them does the trick. IF you can show the full code you're using I can tell you exactly.

Comment: I'm using echo in just 1 place. Where I've written down my PHP Code it states echo json_encode($all_images);

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression would make life much easier for you. Instead of using "replace", I would use something like this to gain full control of the strings passing through. The pattern can be enhanced — or made simpler (https://regex101.com/). I hope this gives you an idea. Good luck!

```js
var str = "http://www.blastr.com/sites/blastr/files/Yoda-Meditating.jpg"
var pattern = /([-^\w+ _:]+)(\.(jpe?g|gif|png){1,4})$/gi;
var image = pattern.exec(str);
var fullName = image[0]; //Yoda-Meditating.jpg
var name = image[1]; //Yoda-Meditating
var fullExtension = image[2];//.jpg
var extension = image[3];//jpg
```